# Lightbox is Broken

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I've been using Lightbox for a bit on my site. Up until recently, it was working fine. However, now when I click on an image, no image pops up. The background still dims as if an image was going to show up, but no image appears. It seemed to happen during a period of time when no modifications were being made to the site, so I'm not sure where to look. What might be causing this?

The site is [ZombieSquirrel](http://www.zombiesquirrel.com).

Comment: Looks like http://www.zombiesquirrel.com/z/styles/mobile.css is missing, not sure if that is the cause, however, it needs to be corrected

Comment: That looks like an old reference. I've removed it now. As you said, it didn't fix it, but thanks for pointing it out nonetheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be in issue with your lightbox and your jQuery version conflicting, for instance if I were to change your jQuery version to 1.8, it works again

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: Interesting. I had hoped to move to newer versions of jQuery...is there no way around this? I'll switch it back for now.

Comment: I would suggest going to colorbox which is in my opinion better than lightbox and implements in a similar way.

Comment: I will look into this and perhaps switch over once I get a chance to tinker with the site again.